# Second graphics card not detected

Tags: motherboard, nvidia-graphics-card

I have a ASUS M5A99X motherboard and two Nvidia GeForce GT640. I want to use them for parallel computing using CUDA, so I am only interested in only one card for screen display. When I connect both cards the computer doesn't even boot. With one card installed there's no problem. I haven't installed any OS yet, and I couldn't find any configuration in BIOS setup.
¿How can I solve this?

Comment: "With one card installed there's no problem." Does it matter which card to try? Like do they both work if inserted individually?  Have you ensured your PSU supplies enough power, and that it's hooked up right?

Comment: Yes, I tried both separedtly and they work fine. Now I see that actually 350 W is needed per card, so my power supply is not enough...

Comment: When you say it doesn't boot with both cards. What actually happens? Do you get POST beeps?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Nope, no beep at all. I can just say that the main LED of the motherboard turns green, DRAM and CPU leds (in red) turns on and off repeatedly and after some seconds the CPU light remains on.. no sound and nothing else.

Comment: If you pull out both video cards, do you get POST beeps?  Do you have a speaker hooked to the board to hear the POST beeps (if they ARE occurring)?

Comment: I don't have speakers, actually I can't test the computer until weekend (it is not mine and it is not at my home).

Answer (score 0):

The requeriments (shown here http://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gt640/specifications) says that each card needs 350 Watts, and my power supply is just of 650 W, so the configuration will not work.

UPDATE: Now it works, I mean, both cards are in their slots and the computer is running. Both cards are recognized by system as here:

```
[root@localhost ~]# lspci | grep -i VGA
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK107 [GeForce GT 640] (rev a1)
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK107 [GeForce GT 640] (rev a1)
```

The exact reason of the problem remains unknown for me. What I did was simply install an OS, then tried to boot the OS with both cards and it worked. I dont know if BIOS found something useful instaled by OS (Fedora 20) that allowed it to start.

Comment: No, 350W is the minimum system power requirement. The maximum power for each card is 65W, so your PSU should actually be enough. That's not the reason your card is not being detected.

Comment: I have no more information about the problem :(